# Color a sprite a different color from its texture

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I was trying to change the color of a SKSPriteNode from green to white. It is originally green in its texture. However, in some cases, I want it to be completely white. I tried doing this:

```
func loadBackButton() {
    backButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "BackButton")
    backButton.color = .white
    backButton.size = CGSize(width: self.size.width * CGFloat(0.125), height: self.size.width * CGFloat(0.125))
    backButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width * CGFloat(-0.426), y: self.size.height * CGFloat(0.449))
    self.addChild(backButton)
}
```

That did not change anything. So I did a little research and tried doing this instead:

```
func loadBackButton() {
    backButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "BackButton")
    backButton.colorBlendFactor = 1
    backButton.color = .white
    backButton.size = CGSize(width: self.size.width * CGFloat(0.125), height: self.size.width * CGFloat(0.125))
    backButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width * CGFloat(-0.426), y: self.size.height * CGFloat(0.449))
    self.addChild(backButton)
}
```

However, that also didn't change anything. Does anyone know why is it not changing anything?

Comment: You can't colorize to white with .color . The simplest solution is to create your texture white with photoshop, after colorize it to green.

Comment: try: backButton.texture = nil

Comment: @ChristianCerri, that would turn off the entire texture leaving only a white square

Comment: @Knight0fDragon er... OP said "I want it to be completely white"?

Comment: @ChristianCerri "it" as in the texture, which can mean visible pixels only,

Comment: "it" as in SKSpriteNode, which means all pixels (previous 2 uses of "it" refer to SKSpriteNode). Anyway, it was a suggestion, no big deal, OP seems to have lost interest. BTW like your answer but lots of weird effects with SKCropNode and SKLightNode - I have dropped SKCropNode from my projects.

Comment: PS did you see my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44713043/extend-skaction-to-override-timingmode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always add an overlay using an SKCropNode and a white sprite node if you need it to go white.

Basically:

```
    let croppedNode = SKCropNode()
    croppedNode.maskNode = sprite.copy() as? SKNode
    sprite.addChild(croppedNode)
    let whiteNode = SKSpriteNode(color:.white,size:sprite.size)
    croppedNode.addChild(whiteNode)
    croppedNode.zPosition = 1
```